# I want to generate fibonacci series. Here is my code it is not generating the required fibonacci series

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, fibonacci, function-definition

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fib(int x)
{
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 1;
    int next = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < x-1 ; ++i)
    {
        next = number1 + number2;
        number2 = next;
    }
    return next;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 40;
    cout << fib(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what I did wrong. It is not generating the series I want. I want to generate fibonacci series from a given number.

Comment: try `number1 = number2;` before `number2 = next;`

Comment: You probably want to collect the FIBO values you calculated in a `std::vector<int>`, and return that one from the `fib()` function. In the step after calling `fib()`, you insert a loop to print all the results.

Comment: The easiest way to get the answer is to debug your program. If you don't know how, then at least check the return value of your function for a few small values. Also, you may insert `std::cout << ...` inside the `for` loop to see how it works. Hint: when `number1` is ever being changed in you loop?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code by executing it yourself:

```
int number1 = 0;
int number2 = 1;
int next = 0;
```

then enter the loop:

```
next = number1 + number2 = 0 + 1 = 1;
number2 = next = 1;
```

so, you have

```
next = 1
number1 = 0
number2 = 1
```

Next iteration:

```
next = number1 + number2 = 0 + 1 = 1;
number2 = next = 1;
```

and you still have

```
next = 1
number1 = 0
number2 = 1
```

and this will repeat for the entire loop.
Note that the value of `number1` is zero and never changes, so the addition will always give the value of `number2`.

At the end of each loop iteration, `number2` should hold the sum so far, and `number1` should have the previous value of `number2` (that is, the previous "sum so far").
You're missing that last crucial step:

```
next = number1 + number2;
number1 = number2;
number2 = next;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this for loop

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < x-1 ; ++i)
{
    next = number1 + number2;
    number2 = next;
}
```

you forgot to set a new value for the variable `number1`. So the variable `number1` is always equal to `0`.

Also there is no great sense to declare the function parameter as having the signed integer type `int`. You should use an unsigned integer type. And it is desirable to use as the return type an unsigned integer type that can store a more large range of values.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

unsigned long long fib( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned long long int first = 0;
    unsigned long long int second = 1;
    
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        second += std::exchange( first, second );
    }
    
    return first;
}

int main() 
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 41; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << fib( i ) << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986 102334155
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing is, that your function returns only one value, consider using void function (with cout << ...;) instead of int one.

There is also problem with your function connected with this part

```
next = number1 + number2;
number2 = next;
```

let's see, number1 is always '0', number2 is always '1', because:

next = 0 + 1; which is always '1'
number2 = 1; which is always next, that means it is always '1'

**You have to change it to this**

! Fibonacci series starts with value of '0' !

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void fib(int x) {
    int number1 = 0, number2 = 1, next = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cout << number1 << " ";
        next = number1 + number2;
        number1 = number2;
        number2 = next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int n = 40;
    fib(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's see what happens now:

```
cout << number1 << " "; // (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...)
next = number1 + number2; // (next = {0 + 1, 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 2 + 3, ...}) 
number1 = number2; // (number1 = {1, 1, 2, 3, ...})
number2 = next; // (number2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, ...})
```

And thats it.. :)

ps. think about recursive version, i think it is much easier than iterative one.